# Using ViewBag from a different controller?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, view, viewbag

I have an action method VerifyNewUser() that gets called when the user clicks a url in their email (registration verification url).

The action method sets a bool property in the ViewBag,  updates the user to a verified user, then I load the home page with the user automatically signed in. In the /Home/Index view I want to check the ViewBag for the property I set and display a jquery ui dialog if its true.

However, my ViewBag is null and the script gets skipped. Note I store the message in the homeController.ViewBag so I thought this would work. Perhaps theres a better way to do it this without a ViewBag?

```
public ActionResult VerifyNewUser()
    {
        if(everything checks out)  
        {
              HomeController homeController = new HomeController();
              homeController.ViewBag.RegisterationLoad = true;
              homeController.ViewBag.VerificationMessage = "Thank you! Your account has been activated";
              return View("../Home/Index", null);
        }
    }
```

nothing special in Home controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index(){ 
        return View();
    }
```

In the home view i have this code thats supposed to checks if the homepage is being loaded after clicking the verification url and should display a jquery ui dialog:

```
   @if (ViewBag.RegistrationLoad == "true")
   {
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("<div></div>").html("<span>@ViewBag.VerificationMessage</span>").dialog({
        width: 365, height: 165, minWidth: 365, minHeight: 165, maxWidth: 365, maxHeight: 165,
        autoOpen: true, modal: true, dialogClass: 'noTitleDialog', position: "center",
        buttons: {
            "Ok": function () {
                $(this).remove();
            }
        }
    });
</script>   
   }
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: @ShankarSangoli 's answer appears to be what you want to do but one thing I noticed is the line `@if (ViewBag.RegistrationLoad == "true")` should throw an exception if this line is actually being executed because `==` will not know how to compare `bool` and `string`.

Comment: If on the other hand you are trying to access a `ViewBag` property in one `Action` that was created/set in another `Action` then you will need another solution which I can post an answer to if that were the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use any controller to set the data attributes inside `ViewBag`. Just set it normally and it can be accessible inside any view. Just make sure you use it correctly. In your code you are setting a boolean flag inside `ViewBag` and you are comparing it against a string which will always fail.

Try this.

```
public ActionResult VerifyNewUser()
{
    if(everything checks out)  
    {
          ViewBag.RegisterationLoad = true;
          ViewBag.VerificationMessage = "Thank you! Your account has been activated";
          return View("../Home/Index", null);
    }
}
```

In the view

```
   @if (ViewBag.RegistrationLoad == true)
   { 
        .....
        .....
   }
```